# How to get cells of each table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple tables on my html file, now I just wanted to see how many `td` elements are there in each table. I am trying this code:

```
function process() {
    let arr= $('table');
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        let table = arr[i];
        let cells = table.find('tr').find('td');
        console.log(cells.length);
    }
}
```

But I am getting error as find is not a function error at `table.find('tr').find('td');`

What is the correct way to fix this?

Comment: `tables[i]` should be `tables.eq(i)` if you need them to remain as a jQuery object to continue to use jQuery methods off of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let table = tables[i];`

When you perform `[#]` on a jQuery object, the result is that the element on the result stack is pulled out of the jQuery object and is no longer wrapped by one.  So at that point you cannot use jQuery methods upon it, if those methods are defined on the `jQuery.fn` scope.

To fix this, you should either use `tables.eq(i)` to get the element, as `eq()` keeps the element in a jQuery object, or put the element back in a `$()` to wrap it again.

Personally I advocate the usage of `eq()` as it is one less step you have to write to re-wrap it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like that

```
function process() {
    let tables = $('table');
    for(let i=0; i<tables.length; i++) {
        let table = tables[i];
        let cells = $(table).find('tr > td');
        console.log(cells.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain why this is necessary, otherwise this is close to being a code only answer, which are considered low quality

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure jQuery way to do this:

```
totalCount = 0;
$('table').each(function(a, b) {
    totalCount += $(b).find('td').length
})
console.log(totalCount)
```

```js
totalCount = 0;
$('table').each(function(a, b) {
    totalCount += $(b).find('td').length
})
console.log(totalCount)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```